# gst-rtsp-server

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

In ubuntu / debian there is a package which is gst-rtsp-server-0.10 which is the gstreamer rtsp server package however the current version in ubuntu seems to be somewhat buggy / unstable

How would I go about getting a new version packaged?